Send request with too large Header but got ENHANCE_YOUR_CALM error code rather than Status 431
My client send a request with size >8KB to my Nginx reverse proxy server. There is an upstream gRPC server behind Nginx.
When I check the error code, it is  rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = closing transport due to: connection error: desc = \"error reading from server: EOF\", received prior goaway: code: ENHANCE_YOUR_CALM
I am so confused with why did I receive such error code?
I know that the limitation of the size of header is specified in my nginx rule. By default, it is
large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;

Does the gRPC client interpret the response from Nginx wrongly?
After I increase the limitation, the error code does not show up again.
According to the description of Nginx document,
A request line cannot exceed the size of one buffer, or the 414 (Request-URI Too Large) error is returned to the client. A request header field cannot exceed the size of one buffer as well, or the 400 (Bad Request) error is returned to the client.


Is the grpc keepalive FAQ helpful? https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_keepalive.html
